# strcmp script reading serial monitor failing

Tags: c, string, character, serial-monitor

I have a script reading the serial monitor and looking for an "OK" response.  I am able to capture the OK response in a variable named message and print it to the serial monitor, but when I attempt to use the message variable in an if statement it is not performing as expected.  When the variable message = OK the statement below is still giving a false.  Does anyone know where the issue might be?

```
 if (strcmp (message,"OK") == 0) {
  Serial.println("true");
 }
 else {
  Serial.println("false");
 }
```

The complete code:

```
//#include <HardwareSerial.h>
const unsigned int MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 12;

void setup() {
Serial2.begin(115200,SERIAL_8N1); //open modem serial port
Serial.println("serial ports are open");
}

void loop() {
  
 Serial2.write("AT\r\n");

 while (Serial2.available() > 0){
   //Create a place to hold the incoming message
   static char message[MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
   static unsigned int message_pos = 0;
   
   //Read the next available byte in the serial receive buffer
   char inByte = Serial2.read();
   
   //Message coming in (check not terminating character) and guard for over message size
   if ( inByte != '\n' && (message_pos < MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH - 1) )
   {
     //Add the incoming byte to our message
     message[message_pos] = inByte;
     message_pos++;
   }
   
   //Full message received...
   else
   {
     //Add null character to string
     message[message_pos] = '\0';
        //Print the message (or do other things)
     Serial.println("loop");
     delay(100);
     Serial.println(message);
     //Reset for the next message
      message_pos = 0;
     
     if (strcmp (message,"OK") == 0) {
      Serial.println("true");
     }
     else {
      Serial.println("false");
     }
   }
      
 }
delay(5000);
}
```

Serial monitor looks like this:

```
22:11:51.970 -> serial ports are open
22:12:16.984 -> loop
22:12:17.078 -> AT


22:12:17.078 -> false
22:12:17.078 -> loop
22:12:17.171 -> OK

22:12:17.171 -> false
22:12:17.171 -> loop
22:12:17.266 -> AT


22:12:17.266 -> false
22:12:17.266 -> loop
22:12:17.360 -> OK

22:12:17.360 -> false
```

Comment: After loop why is AT printed?

Comment: BTW, try using `strncmp` instead of `strcmp`. Or you can try printing each byte of message in hex format and see what is the output.

Comment: @kiner_shah The "AT" is the echoed command. -- `strncmp` will match any response beginning with "OK". This is only fine if the following characters can be ignored.

Comment: @kiner_shah changing the code to `strncmp` works for my use case.  I just tested it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The received response is `"OK\r\n"`, so the actual message is `"OK\r"`. It helps for debugging if you temporarily print each received character.

To ignore the echo of the command, insert another `strcmp()` for it and react accordingly, for example do nothing.

Comment: I just edited the code so that the `strcmp` function looks for `"OK\r"` and this works I do still have the problem that AT is being echoed by the modem though and this isn't relevant to my logic.  So it causes by if statement to oscillate between true and false.